# Internal sort ,Tournament sort algorithm that using two heaps explain

Tags: database, algorithm, sorting, heap, memorystream

I am trying to understand the following [tournament sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_sort) (replacement selection), It is a sorting algorithm for doing sorting in the main memory.

Any explanation how this work?

```
Keep two heaps in memory, H1 and H2
read B-2 pages of records, inserting into H1;  #B is buffer size

while (records left) {
  m = H1.removemin();  
  put m in output buffer;
  if (H1 NOT empty)
       read in a new record r (use 1 buffer for input pages);
       if (r < m)  
           H2.insert(r);
       else        
           H1.insert(r);
 else
      H1 = H2;  
      H2.reset();  
      start new output run; 
}
H1.output();  
start new run;  
H2.output();
```

Answer (score 1):

The replacement selection technique is of special interest because the expected length of the runs produced is two times the size of available main memory. This estimation was first proposed by E.H. Friend in and later described by E.F. Moore. In real world applications, input data is usually not random (i.e., it often exhibits some degree of pre-sortedness). In such cases, the runs generated by replacement selection tend to contain even more than 2m records. In fact, for the best case scenario, namely when the input data is already sorted, replacement selection produces only one run.

Given a set of tuples record, status , where record is a record read from the unsorted input and status is a Boolean flag indicating whether the record is active or inactive. Active records are candidates for the current run, while inactive records are saved for the next run. The idea behind the algorithm is as follows: assuming a main memory of size m, we read m records from the unsorted input data, setting its status to active. Then, the tuple with the smallest key and active status is selected and moved to an output file. When a tuple is moved to the output (selection), its place is occupied by another tuple from the input data (replacement). If the record recently read is smaller than the one just written, its status is set to inactive, which means it will be written to the next run. Once all tuples are in the inactive state, the current run file is closed, a new output file is created, and the status of all tuples is reset to active.

You can read more about replacement selection [here](http://wwwlgis.informatik.uni-kl.de/cms/fileadmin/publications/2014/MScThesisDusso2014.pdf).